# Shift-JISに設定しているさくらサーバにwordpressをインストールしたい。

Tags: wordpress, 文字化け

初心者ですので宜しくお願いします。
さくらサーバのphp.iniを以下のように設定すると、Shift-JISのファイルで文字化けがおこらないと、あるサイトに書いて合ったので自分のレンタルサーバにコピペしました。

```
output_buffering              = Off
magic_quotes_gpc              = Off
default_charset               = Shift_JIS
[mbstring]
mbstring.language             = Japanese
mbstring.internal_encoding    = SJIS
mbstring.http_input           = auto
mbstring.http_output          = SJIS
mbstring.encoding_translation = On
mbstring.detect_order         = auto
mbstring.substitute_character = none
```

実際文字化けは起こらず運用していたのですが、
同じドメイン内でwordpressを使用したいと思い、インストールしたところ文字化けしてしまい、
調べてみましたが、解決方法がわかりません。

別にレンタルサーバを借りるのが早いのかもしれないですが、
何かやり方があるのであれば教えていただきたいです。

Comment: この質問は質問から1ヶ月以上経っていますが解決しましたか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPressではUTF-8を利用しているのでそれ以外を指定されると文字化けすることもあるかと思いますが、さくらのレンタルサーバーということなのでドメイン別やサブディレクトリにて設定を上書きする場合、以下の何れかの方法が使えると思います。

- .user.ini ファイルに設定を書く(CGI版のみ)
  CGI版のPHPを利用しているならこの設定が利用可能です。
  WordPressを設置してるディレクトリ(wp-config.phpとかがあるディレクトリ)に`.user.ini`ファイルを作成し、当該の設定を上書きします。

  ```
  default_charset               = UTF-8
  mbstring.internal_encoding    = UTF-8
  mbstring.http_output          = UTF-8
  ```
- .htaccessにて設定を上書きする
  モジュール版PHPを利用している場合はこちらを利用します。
  WordPressの設置ディレクトリに`.htaccess`ファイルが有るはずなので(なければ作り、)以下のように設定します。

  ```
  <IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value default_charset "UTF-8"
    php_value mbstring.internal_encoding "UTF-8"
    php_value mbstring.http_output "UTF-8"
  </IfModule>
  ```